# Trying to make rightBarButton appear after making it disappear using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I currently am working on an app in Swift where in my viewDidLoad() method I have purposely hidden my rightBarButton on my navigation bar like this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(TableViewController.dismiss))
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
```

However, under certain circumstances, I would like to display the rightBarButton.  How would I do this?  What would be the opposite of the above line of code?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to code it again after you set it `nil`, it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Is there not a way where I can perhaps set a boolean or alpha value to hide/show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the bar button item to `nil`, it is gone. Something you can do however, is store the bar button item like so:

`let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(TableViewController.dismiss));`

and then you can make it appear/disappear like so:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
```

then just access the `barButtonItem` whenever you want it to appear/disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of the following two options:

- Keep a reference of your `UIBarButtonItem` and every time you disappear you save it to then when you want to show it again you set the old value.
- Play with the color of the `UIBarButtonItem` and the enabled/disable property to enable the interaction with it.

The first choice always keep a reference globally to the `UIBarButtonItem` and the second need to know the exact color of the original `UIBarButtonItem` to give to its original state:

> First Option:

```
private var isHidden: Bool!
private var righBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func hideButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.isHidden == true {
        self.isHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = righBarButtonItem
    }
    else {

       self.isHidden = true
       righBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
       self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
    }
}
```

> Second Option:

```
@IBAction func hideButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.isHidden == true {
        self.isHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    }
    else {
        self.isHidden = true
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
    }
}
```

In the above examples  I set a variable with the state of the `UIBarButtonItem` for purposes of know the value and and `@IBOutlet` to hide/show the `UIBarButtonItem`. The variable `isHidden` need to set it's initial value in the `viewDidLoad`.

I hope this help you.